# Why FZF does not work when I open it from vim intro?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim, fzf

I am using FZF as my navigation plugin and I created my own vim intro plugin.

- https://github.com/regedarek/vim-intro/blob/master/plugin/vim-intro.vim
- https://github.com/regedarek/fzf-configuration
- https://github.com/regedarek/dotfiles/nvimrc

When I open a VIM my vim-intro shows up but when I open :FZF then choose a file and press enter i see that the name of buffer is changed but buffer is stil vim-intro and when I press enter again buffer is empty.

How to recognise where is a problem? What I am doing wrong?

Preview: https://asciinema.org/a/3rj5twu1b9xabv9ixwrakx0tt

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is an issue with your plugin, but rather one with the integration of fzf inside neovim which has some issues : see https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/206.

One way to fix it is to put

`let g:loaded_python_provider = 1` on the top of your .nvimrc

I personally have stopped used neovim for this particular reason (and use regular vim instead)

Comment: Nope adding this to top of my ``.nvimrc`` didn't help. I also think this is some issue with FZF but strange thing that I don't receive any error.

Comment: Have you seen the link to the github issue ? It might help